# Python form newbie - prefilled forms ..is it possible?

Tags: python, forms, python-2.7, tkinter

some help is badly needed here. 
I have this form python script...
 
 I want to prefill the form fields with information gathered from a file. 
The fields should be prefilled with ip , mask ,gateway,dns and the ip of a webserver on the local network. The ip´s and everything will be in a text file on a usb stick.
Later on this information will be extracted in a text file and written in the ifconfig files of the debian system.
(i must admit i have not worked in python what so ever... i dont really know what im doing.. but apparently i have to do this ...and fast as well .. so im trying my best. 
The script itself will be run from a usb memory stick on couple different debian based systems who needs this information  uppdated
 This is what i did so far.Is it possible to save each fiels as a variable?
 Is it feasible? 
 

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

[Python form picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Tid.png)

#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  namnlös.py
#  
#  Copyright 2017 user <user@oe>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  
#  
from Tkinter import *
import socket
import os
import sys
import commands
sys.stdout = open('/home/user/Skrivbord/newip.txt', 'w')



f = open( "/home/user/Skrivbord/ip.bak", "r" )
uppgifter = []
for line in f:
    uppgifter.append(line)
f.close()
print uppgifter
#Nätverk hämtning från Kentima  
gw = os.popen("ip -4 route show default").read().split()
ip=((([ip for ip in socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2] if not ip.startswith("127.")] or [[(s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 53)), s.getsockname()[0], s.close()) for s in [socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)]][0][1]]) + ["no IP found"])[0])
localip = 'Den aktiva ip är'

################## GUI ##################################

fields = 'Local Ip', 'Mask Adress', 'Gateway adress', 'Dns adress','Web Server adress'
def fetch(entries):
   for entry in entries:
      field = entry[0]
      text  = entry[1].get()
      print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text)) 

def makeform(root, fields):
   entries = []
   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=30, text=field, anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=10, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X, )
      entries.append((field, ent))
   return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   root.title(localip)
   ents = makeform(root, fields)
   root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))   
   b1 = Button(root, text='Avsluta',  command=root.quit)
   b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   b2 = Button(root, text='Spara', command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e))) 
   b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
   root.mainloop()

Comment: `entry.insert(0, some_text)`

Comment: yes, it's feasible, and the way to do it is documented in many places.

Comment: i have search upp and down .. and i cant seem to find the answer...that is why i posted here.. is it possible to post a link in the right direction i would be grateful.

Comment: start here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. As [Goyo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2142055/goyo) pointed out in the comments above, you can use `.insert()` on the `Entry` widget to populate it.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

entry = Entry(root)

entry.pack()

entry.insert(0, "Lorem Ipsum")

root.mainloop()
```

If you're looking for a way to populate it based on some string in a file, then you simply need to read the file in. I imagine this would look something like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

entry = Entry(root)

entry.pack()

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    entry.insert(0, f.read())

root.mainloop()
```